# Is there a way for systemd-resolve to retunr entry in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, network-manager, systemd-resolved

is there a way to make systemd-resolve return entries in /etc/hosts when I do dig on 192.168.0.1 ? I have issue that one software is querying dns and thus ignoring /etc/hosts entries... any ideas ? ( except creating own local dns server )

Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: [The documentation is pretty clear](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/dig.1.html) that `dig` is used to query DNS servers, so there's no reason for it to ever use the lookups stored in `/etc/hosts`. If there are specific addresses you want handled differently, you *might* be able to define them in `~/.digrc`, but this defeats the purpose of the utility. What specifically are you trying to do? Perhaps a different tool will solve your problem 

Comment: There is a way. Edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and make sure the `hosts:` line has "`files`" before "`dns`". Are you  not running `dnsmasq`?

Comment: @Matigo specific situation is, that docker have special plugin called buildx that allows multi arch builds. And it have option to push the build to registry once done. But for some reason it query dns 1.1.1.1 which is not even setup anywhere, instead going through /etc/hosts and so on... I can specify dns servers in docker daemon and than it try to use that... its problem with the buildx, I was just thinking since ubuntu is running systemd-resolve which is some kind of micro dns forwarder in essence, if i can somehow add A record to it :D